python selenium chromedriver geckodriver POST request failed
I am writing a small program to help me automate some repetitive tasks, but I encountered a small issue.
When I access a page, I can successfully reach the hidden page, but when I try to click a button for the next step, I get an ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. In DevTools, I see that a POST request is showing as failed.
I tried disabling HTTP/2 in ChromeDriver, and while the ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR no longer appears,  the POST action remains pending.
How can I resolve this?
I can access it normally on Chrome and proceed to the next step.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
import time


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument("--disable-http2")


chrome_driver_path = r'.\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(chrome_driver_path), options=options)

try:
    driver.get("about:blank")


    script = """
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.method = 'post';
    form.action = 'https://example.com/1/123';

    var input1 = document.createElement('input');
    input1.type = 'hidden';
    input1.name = 'key';
    input1.value = '11111';
    form.appendChild(input1);

    form.submit();
    """
    driver.execute_script(script)

    time.sleep(600)


except Exception as e:
    print(f"error: {e}")


I have tried using chromedriver and geckodriver to access it manually, but it still fails

driver.get("about:blank") could be an issue... the error suggests a malformed request.  So check inspector for the actual POST.  (usually easiest to just right-click on the network request and choose, "Copy HAR File" and open that in notepad.)

Thank you for your reply. I found the reason: the website has measures in place to prevent automated applications
